# Primefaces TabMenu active tab remembered on logout

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

As the title explains by itself, I have an issue with managing the currently active tab in the tab menu. I'm using JSF 2.1 w/ PF 3.4. Here is the code fragment with the tab menu:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{navigationMB.activeIndex}"  >
        <p:menuitem value="Početna" action="#{navigationMB.navigateStudent('home')}" icon="ui-icon-home" />
        <p:menuitem value="Konsultacije" action="#{navigationMB.navigateStudent('konsultacije')}"  icon="ui-icon-search" />
        <p:menuitem value="Zakazivanje" action="#{navigationMB.navigateStudent('zakazivanje')}"  icon="ui-icon-document"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Profesori" action="#{navigationMB.navigateStudent('profesori')}"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Moj profil" action="#{navigationMB.navigateStudent('profil')}"  icon="ui-icon-person" />
    </p:tabMenu>
</h:form>
```

Here is the code of the backing bean which serves for the sole purpose of navigating that tab menu:

```
@Named(value = "navigationMB")
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationMB {

private int activeIndex = 0;
public NavigationMB() {

}

public String navigateStudent(String page) {

    System.out.println("go to page " + page);

    if ("home".equals(page)) {
        activeIndex = 0;
        return "/student/home?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    if ("konsultacije".equals(page)) {
        activeIndex = 1;
        return "/student/allConsults?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    if ("zakazivanje".equals(page)) {
        activeIndex = 2;
        return "/student/newConsult?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    if ("profesori".equals(page)) {
        activeIndex = 3;
        return "/student/allProfessors?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    if ("profil".equals(page)) {
        activeIndex = 4;
        return "/student/profile?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    return "";
}
```

This runs fine when just browsing, but when I logout (invalidate the session) and later return with same or different user, the activeIndex is remembered. Am I not understanding something here? I suppose that the request scoped bean would be created every time there's a navigation action, and even if the user doesn't navigate anywhere, the integer I set to 0 would always point to "home" but it doesn't. 
Any help would be awesome.

edit:

It seems that even without logging out, when two users (two tabs in browser) navigate around, if user 1 clicks on, for instance, tab menu item 2, and user 2 refreshes his page, user 2 will see tab menu item 2 selected as well, and vice versa.

edit2: I made a mistake with the previous edit, please forget about this above (I didn't notice that refresh on user 2 side actually loads user 1 with his view).

Comment: Cleared your browser cache and observed the same behaviour in more than one browser?

Comment: Haven't tried clearing cache, I don't suppose that it is user friendly to clear the cache every now and then for the application to work properly :) I tried it on Chrome and IE, same issue.

Comment: Just to be clear, "activeIndex is remembered" means when you startup a new session, the previously active tab is enabled?

Comment: @kolossus Yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: Add two debug methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` and debug exactly when the bean is constructed and destroyd. In your request scoped bean, they shold probably be called just after one another. I would almost think that your `int activeIndex` is static, but it seems it's not.

Comment: @BorkoS, try JSF scoping on your managed bean instead (use annotations from `javax.faces.bean.*` and see the result. This is highly unusual though

Comment: @kolossus Tried those annotations, still no good. Thank you.

Comment: @Magnus Tengdahl PostConstuct gets called immediatelly on deployment, and PreDestroy never. Also, I see now that maybe I should have mention that I'm also using Spring. I'm still new at this. To my understanding now, Spring is managing the beans, and when I run it on Glassfish, it says "preinstalling singletons blah blah blah and the list of all my managed beans".. Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: You got the answer to your behaviour right there. The bean is created **once**, hence it's state is persistent during the lifetime of the application. It is not request scoped at all. I would try to use the Spring annotation for scoping: `@Scope("request")`. Maybe some configuration is needed if you want to use other annotations.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl Yes, your suggestion was correct, now the bean gets instantiated only on **request**. I have been using this scope annotation wrong in many places in my project, but now I get it. Thanks, sir. In order for activeIndex and navigating to work as I wanted, I only needed to make it a session-scope bean, as I invalidate the session on logout, so it "turns" to Home page on next login.

Comment: Glad it worked. :) I post it as a proper answer so you can set it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed among the comments of the question, the bean is not recognized as being request scoped. It is created during application startup and lives as long as the application is running.

As Spring is used, using Spring annotations will resolve this issue:

```
@Scope("request")
public class NavigationMB {
}
```

For a request scoped bean, or:

```
@Scope("session")
public class NavigationMB {
}
```

to make it session scoped.